# Django s3 static files serve

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 to serve static files for application hosted on heroku.I have made s3 bucket public and enabled static website hosting. Issue is i don't have any ssl certificate so i need to access it without https but when static tag creates urls for my application static files in templates it is automatically prepending http headers.How should i avoid it so i can access static files on my website without purchasing ssl?

```
settings.py
Custom_domain='xxx.s3-website-us-west-2-amazonaws.com'
STATIC_URL="%s/"%Custom_domain
STATICFILES_STORAGE='storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

Similar for media_url and default_file_storage
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help
[Django AWS S3 tutorial](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/)

Comment: Already read it, didn't help. This is written with use of https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full url including protocol.

```
 STATIC_URL="http://%s/" % Custom_domain
```

In fact, it wouldn't work at all without the protocol; the browser would just interpret it as a relative path in the current domain.

Note though that you can easily get a free ssl certificate from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: It is not working even with full url.https is getting appended automatically

Comment: You're going to need to show the template where you are using this, and an extract of the rendered HTML.

Comment: Daniel I solved the issue by using AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False